# How to display array value to my template?

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

I am using plugin for wordpress,

import-users-from-csv plugin upload csv error log in text file.

i need help error log display same screen, array value display `print_r();`

but display in my screen error on my `foreach` loop.help with correct my `foreach` loop.

```
 Array
(
    [0] => WP_Error Object
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [existing_user_login] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Sorry, that username already exists!
                        )

                )

            [error_data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => WP_Error Object
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [existing_user_login] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Sorry, that username already exists!
                        )

                )

            [error_data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

I am using display this array value in this foreach but value not display, Help with us

```
foreach($nerrors as $key=>$err)
        {
            echo $err['errors']['existing_user_login'][$key];


        }
```

Comment: Lack of information, what templating engine? Maybe framework? And what you tried?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your idea of *display*? Currently I do not see why `echo $your_json` is not a valid answer.

Comment: wordpress import-users-from-csv plugin display error log display on txt file. but i need display same screen i am using function, error value display print_r(); but not display in my screen. can u help with how to display in foreach.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => WP_Error Object
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [existing_user_login] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Sorry, that username already exists!
                        )

                )

            [error_data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

) this is an array value. how to display foreach loop.

Comment: tag wordpress in your question to tell folks that you are using wordpress templates

Comment: foreach($nerrors as $key=>$err)
  {
   echo $err['errors']['existing_user_login'][$key];
   

  } this is my foreach loop can u help with. display value right format

Comment: you can use javascript's `console.log()` to display/monitor anything without having the user seeing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited

```
foreach($nerrors as $err)
    {
        echo $err->errors['existing_user_login'][0];

    }
```

errors are object element , not array.

Please check it.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in my screen

Comment: function display_error($nerrors = '')
 {
  if(isset($nerrors))
  {
  foreach($nerrors as $err)
  {
      echo $err->errors['existing_user_login'][0];
     
  }  
 
  }
    } 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(); display error on my screen how to display this function value